# Mouse scroll wheel is intermitent with Win7 Remote Desktop session with Debian machine

Tags: remote-desktop, mouse, scroll-wheel

I have a Debian Linux machine which I access with Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection (RDP).

Frequently the mouse scroll wheel quits in the remote desktop session. If I go back to the Windows desktop  and click on any open app, the mouse scroll wheel works. If I now go back to the remote session the scroll wheel will work for a short while at which point I have repeat the process to get the scroll wheel working again.

Very frustrating. It seems the Remote Desktop Connection client is doing something with the mouse. This is recently started and I am at a lose at where to fix this.

Any thoughts?